# Cannot assign "<django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x0000027C3917EFD0>": "Post.login" must be a "UserAccount" instance

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема? при авторизации
Авторизация через jwt

settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',

    ],

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer', 'JWT'),
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=365),
    'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken',
    )
}
```

views.py

```
class PostView(APIView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostListSerializer
    # permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        posts = Post.objects.all()
        serializer = PostListSerializer(posts, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = PostListSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save(login=self.request.user)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

на фронтенд входит в аккаунт
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но в api пользователь показывается не авторизованным

```
{
    "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}
```

при попытке создать пост
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

если зайти http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ в admin панель этих проблем нет

Answer (score 0):

проблема была на фронте, нужно было передавать токен при создании поста[image: введите сюда описание изображения]